# Is there a testing environment for terraform?

Tags: terraform

wanted to know if there are some testing websites for terraform where not really test output of terraform resource, but test some variable e.g. given: some input

```sh
x = [
    {
      name = first
      condition = {
        age = "1"
      }
      action = {
        type = "Delete"
      }
    },{
      name: second
      condition = {
        age = "2"
      }
      action = {
        type = "Delete"
      }
   }
]
```

wanted to test how to get to second variable in online live runtime

smth similar to regex.101.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is terraform [console](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/console.html):

> This command provides an interactive command-line console for **evaluating and experimenting with expressions**. This is useful for testing interpolations before using them in configurations, and for interacting with any values currently saved in state.

For example, you can put your `x` variable in a file called `test.tf` (after you fix its syntax):

```
variable "x" {

default = [
        {
          name = "first",
          condition = {
            age = "1"
          }
          action = {
            type = "Delete"
          }
        },{
          name = "second",
          condition = {
            age = "2"
          }
          action = {
            type = "Delete"
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

Then in the same folder where the file is:

```
terraform console
```

And then in terminal just load your variable:

```
> var.x
[
  {
    "action" = {
      "type" = "Delete"
    }
    "condition" = {
      "age" = "1"
    }
    "name" = "first"
  },
  {
    "action" = {
      "type" = "Delete"
    }
    "condition" = {
      "age" = "2"
    }
    "name" = "second"
  },
]
```

Or check how to get the value desired:

```
> var.x[1].name
second
> var.x[1]["name"]
second
```